# Execute sql insert statements via sql alchemy within for loop

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, singlestore

I need to extract a bunch of records within a singlestore database and insert the records into another table. For performance, the ideal way to do this is to create a query string with an Insert Into statement and iterate through on a daily basis.

I can't seem to get python to execute the query in the database, but it appears to run successfully?

```
fh = 'file_containing_insert_select_query.sql'
qry = open(fh).read()
for i in range(2):
    qry_new = some_custom_function_to_replace_dates(qry, i)
    engine = tls.custom_engine_function()
    engine.execute(qry_new)
```

I've verified that the sql statements created by my custom function can be copy/pasted to a sql editor and executed successfully, but it won't run in python... any thoughts?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Or it just would not return any results?

Comment: Maybe you need to commit the transaction ?

Comment: Is there an error message that you are getting?

Comment: Was not receiving any errors no, the python statements would run, but nothing would happen in my database. @IanWilson was correct, I ended up needing to construct slightly different and commit my transaction, at which point my database updated.

Answer (score 1):

After execution of the above query, you need to send a `'commit'` query to database using `connection.commit()`
(Where connection contains the Database connection credentials and ip address) so it can save the no. of rows inserted via python program.

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to run really fast, it’s usually better to use set-oriented SQL, like INSERT INTO targetTbl … SELECT FROM …;

That way, it doesn’t have to round-trip through the client app.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32444716)